# Databinding Entry in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to capture the value of the entry in a Login text box in Xamarin Forms. I've created the class, data bound in xmal, but running into build errors when compiling for iOS. Any pointers much appreciated.

Login.xmal:

```
 <Entry x:Name="{Binding Source = AppLoginUsername;}" Placeholder="Username" 
                   Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="300" />
```

FormEntry Class.cs

using System;
namespace SGC.Class

```
{
    public class FormEntryBindings
    {
        public FormEntryBindings()
        {


        }


        public static string AppLoginUserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Home.cs (Grabs the username entered in Login page and figures out the CustomerID)

```
private async void getCustBalance()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            string x = FormEntryBindings.AppLoginUserName;

            int custid =  GetCustomerId(x);
```

The errors are:

Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Invalid expression term '='

Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Comment: remove the semicolon and whitespace "Source = AppLoginUsername;"

Comment: If I do this: <Entry x:Name="{Binding AppLoginUsername}" Placeholder="Username" 
                   Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="300" /> I get the same errors plus ; expected

Comment: generally compile errors should tell you a specific file and line number

Comment: how do you bind your model (viewmodel) with the view?

Comment: What do you wan to access? If you want to access the `Entry`,  you can just give it a name without binding. If you want to capture the value of the entry, you can just get `entry.text` without binding. What is `AppLoginUserName` use for here?

Comment: Jack - what you mentioned is what I want to do. I simply want to take the value of the username which is a seperate view (as noted above) - lets say I call it x:Name =LoginName and on the code behind of ANOTHER VIEW, I want to access that value. I should be able to do something like string x = LoginName.Text; but since this is on another view, it doesn't work. (Works fine if I do this only on the code behind on where the login username text box exists...just doesn't work if I'm calling from a different code behind.)

Comment: So the solution to my issue was to use parameters when pushing to a new page. On Login code behind..I used:  Navigation.PushAsync(new Home(LoginName)); I will mark one of the answers as the solution as it answered my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on the comments, I think your problem is that you can get the `AppLoginUserName` in the login page, however,you want use the `AppLoginUserName` in another page(another view).

I would give your several suggestions:

1.You can pass the value to the page where you want to use.

2.Use `Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences`.

You can save the `AppLoginUserName` once the user has **logged in**:

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

Preferences.Set("AppLoginUserName", "value");
```

At **another view** where you want to use, you can get the value:

```
var myValue = Preferences.Get("AppLoginUserName", "default_value");
```

And remove the key from preferences when the user has **logged out or under other situation**:

```
Preferences.Remove("my_key");
```

You can refer:[essentials/preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fios&tabs=ios)

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you just give it a name, and bind the text?
Eg 
x:Name=“User” Text=“{Binding AppLoginUsername}”...

Comment: If I do this... <Entry x:Name="uLoginUsername" Text="{Binding AppLoginUsername}" Placeholder="Username" 
                   Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="300" /> , it does compile without error but I cannot access the value that was typed inside the textbook when logging in. So this doesn't work... private async void getCustBalance()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

           

            string x = uLoginUsername.Text; 

            int custid =  GetCustomerId(x);

Comment: Just add the mode to twoway, Text=“{Binding AppLoginUsername, mode=TwoWay}” from C# use the property not the control. So you will use GestCustomerId(AppLoginUsername). Suggest you have a look at MVVM

Answer (score 1):

You can’t bind the name. Name is something that generates the code and you can’t change the name of the variable on the fly.